# How to check if any Checkbox is checked in Angular

Tags: angularjs, checkbox

Is there any function or ng-*something* to check if any of the displayed Checkboxes are checked?

I have the values through the **ng-click="function()"** and pass the values through. I can go by foot and check my array if any value is inside.

> I want to activate/deactivate the "next"-button if any Checkbox is
>   checked.

What's the easiest way?

Comment: The accepted answer seem unnecessarily complicated. Please see mine below.

Comment: @Antoine It's not. Your solutions just covers ONE checkbox, I want to see it in the controller if one of the dozens of checkboxes is checked.

Comment: You're right. I must have misread your question. I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
function ChckbxsCtrl($scope, $filter) {
    $scope.chkbxs = [{
        label: "Led Zeppelin",
        val: false
    }, {
        label: "Electric Light Orchestra",
        val: false
    }, {
        label: "Mark Almond",
        val: false
    }];

    $scope.$watch("chkbxs", function(n, o) {
        var trues = $filter("filter")(n, {
            val: true
        });
        $scope.flag = trues.length;
    }, true);
}
```

And a template:

```
<div ng-controller="ChckbxsCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="chk in chkbxs">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="chk.val" />
        <label>{{chk.label}}</label>
    </div>
    <div ng-show="flag">I'm ON when band choosed</div>
</div>
```

Working: http://jsfiddle.net/cherniv/JBwmA/

**UPDATE:** Or you can go little bit different way , without using `$scope`'s `$watch()` method, like:

```
$scope.bandChoosed = function() {
    var trues = $filter("filter")($scope.chkbxs, {
        val: true
    });
    return trues.length;
}
```

And in a template do:

```
<div ng-show="bandChoosed()">I'm ON when band choosed</div>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uzs4sgnp/

Comment: this is a damn nice solution. for my understanding: what does $filter("filter)(n, {val:true}); ?

Comment: @askrufus ,  it is only filtering out all those that have val=true at their model' object  , which means that they are "checked". If there is at least one like this - then flag is raised. Simple and elegant!  ;)

Comment: Doesn't the watch in this case add significant overhead?

Comment: @Petrogad, good catch, definitely not the most efficient way!.

Comment: What if checkbox numbers are dynamic ..Than we cant keep $scope.chkbxs ??

Comment: given example has predefined number of checkbox, what if $scope.chkbxs is unknown and {val :  false} is not there ?

Comment: @mayank can you please create an example of how you want it , in jsfiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mayankbhadauria/sksr3u2a/3/       is that a ryt way to do this 
?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mayankbhadauria/sksr3u2a/5/ try this some updates were missing . sorry

Comment: @mayank so instead of using hard-coded values in html just use dynamic array in controller , like in my example: http://jsfiddle.net/uzs4sgnp/

Comment: i am getting my checkbox length from API which i use to parse and than create DOM, I cant change API response that's a issue.

Comment: Why this convoluted way when  we can simply use http://stackoverflow.com/a/29870260/193634 ?

Comment: Instead of an Angular filter, you can use vanilla JavaScript:
`$scope.bandChoosed = function() {
    return $scope.chkbxs.reduce((acc, cur) => acc.val || cur.val);
};`

Answer (score 25):

If you don't want to use a watcher, you can do something like this:

```
<input type='checkbox' ng-init='checkStatus=false' ng-model='checkStatus' ng-click='doIfChecked(checkStatus)'>
```

Comment: I had to change `ng-click` for `ng-change` to work it properly

Answer (score 24):

If you have only one checkbox, you can do this easily with just ng-model:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="checked"/>
<button ng-disabled="!checked"> Next </button>
```

And initialize $scope.checked in your Controller (default=false). The [official doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit) discourages the use of ng-init in that case.

Answer (score 9):

Try to think in terms of a model and what happens to that model when a checkbox is checked.

Assuming that each checkbox is bound to a field on the model with ng-model then the property on the model is changed whenever a checkbox is clicked:

```
<input type='checkbox' ng-model='fooSelected' />
<input type='checkbox' ng-model='baaSelected' />
```

and in the controller:

```
$scope.fooSelected = false;
$scope.baaSelected = false;
```

The next button should only be available under certain circumstances so add the ng-disabled 
directive to the button:

```
<button type='button' ng-disabled='nextButtonDisabled'></button>
```

Now the next button should only be available when either fooSelected is true or baaSelected is true and we need to watch any changes to these fields to make sure that the next button is made available or not:

```
$scope.$watch('[fooSelected,baaSelected]', function(){
    $scope.nextButtonDisabled = !$scope.fooSelected && !scope.baaSelected;
}, true );
```

The above assumes that there are only a few checkboxes that affect the availability of the next button but it could be easily changed to work with a larger number of checkboxes and use $watchCollection to check for changes.

Answer (score 1):

This is re-post for insert code also.
This example included:
- One object list
- Each object hast child list.
Ex:

```
var list1 = {
    name: "Role A",
    name_selected: false,
    subs: [{
      sub: "Read",
      id: 1,
      selected: false
    }, {
      sub: "Write",
      id: 2,
      selected: false
    }, {
      sub: "Update",
      id: 3,
      selected: false
    }],
  };
```

I'll 3 list like above and i'll add to a one object list

```
newArr.push(list1);
  newArr.push(list2);
  newArr.push(list3);
```

Then i'll do how to show checkbox with multiple group:

```
$scope.toggleAll = function(item) {
    var toogleStatus = !item.name_selected;
    console.log(toogleStatus);
    angular.forEach(item, function() {
      angular.forEach(item.subs, function(sub) {
        sub.selected = toogleStatus;
      });
    });
  };

  $scope.optionToggled = function(item, subs) {
    item.name_selected = subs.every(function(itm) {
      return itm.selected;
    })
    $scope.txtRet = item.name_selected;
  }
```

HTML:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in itemDisplayed" class="ng-scope has-pretty-child">
      <div>
        <ul>
          <input type="checkbox" class="checkall" ng-model="item.name_selected" ng-click="toggleAll(item)"><span>{{item.name}}</span>
          <div>
            <li ng-repeat="sub in item.subs" class="ng-scope has-pretty-child">
              <input type="checkbox" kv-pretty-check="" ng-model="sub.selected" ng-change="optionToggled(item,item.subs)"><span>{{sub.sub}}</span>
            </li>
          </div>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <span>{{txtRet}}</span>
    </li>
```

Fiddle: [example](http://jsfiddle.net/sinh_nguyen/b22fLv1t/)

Answer (score 0):

I've a sample for multiple data with their subnode 
3 list , each list has attribute and child attribute:

```
var list1 = {
    name: "Role A",
    name_selected: false,
    subs: [{
        sub: "Read",
        id: 1,
        selected: false
    }, {
        sub: "Write",
        id: 2,
        selected: false
    }, {
        sub: "Update",
        id: 3,
        selected: false
    }],
};
var list2 = {
    name: "Role B",
    name_selected: false,
    subs: [{
        sub: "Read",
        id: 1,
        selected: false
    }, {
        sub: "Write",
        id: 2,
        selected: false
    }],
};
var list3 = {
    name: "Role B",
    name_selected: false,
    subs: [{
        sub: "Read",
        id: 1,
        selected: false
    }, {
        sub: "Update",
        id: 3,
        selected: false
    }],
};
```

Add these to Array :

```
newArr.push(list1);
newArr.push(list2);
newArr.push(list3);
$scope.itemDisplayed = newArr;
```

Show them in html:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in itemDisplayed" class="ng-scope has-pretty-child">
    <div>
        <ul>
            <input type="checkbox" class="checkall" ng-model="item.name_selected" ng-click="toggleAll(item)" />
            <span>{{item.name}}</span>
            <div>
                <li ng-repeat="sub in item.subs" class="ng-scope has-pretty-child">
                    <input type="checkbox" kv-pretty-check="" ng-model="sub.selected" ng-change="optionToggled(item,item.subs)"><span>{{sub.sub}}</span>
                </li>
            </div>
        </ul>
    </div>
</li>
```

And here is the solution to check them:

```
$scope.toggleAll = function(item) {
    var toogleStatus = !item.name_selected;
    console.log(toogleStatus);
    angular.forEach(item, function() {
        angular.forEach(item.subs, function(sub) {
            sub.selected = toogleStatus;
        });
    });
};

$scope.optionToggled = function(item, subs) {
    item.name_selected = subs.every(function(itm) {
        return itm.selected;
    })
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sinh_nguyen/uzs4sgnp/99/) demo