# How to handle checkboxlist in AngularJS in Add and Edit operation?

Tags: angularjs

I am new to AngularJS and facing one problem with multiple check-boxes. I have one registration form in which I have choices of colors which comes from database.

```
$scope.ColorList = { { ID: 1,Name:"Red" },{ ID: 2,Name:"Green" },{ ID: 3,Name:"Blue" }};
```

I am using below code to render checkbox in form.

```
<tr>
  <td>Favorite Colors</td>
  <td>
     <label data-ng-repeat="c in item.ColorList">
        <input type="checkbox" value="{{c.ID}}" /><span>{{c.Name}}</span> 
     </label>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Now, during add operation, checkboxes renders properly... But how to bind checkboxes with model so that I get an array of selected checkboxes?

Also during edit time, I need to pre-select checkboxes to display user's saved choices.

So how to achieve it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @DharemeshSolanki is that a typo shouldn't it be `[ { ID:1, Name:"Red"} ...] `

Comment: You can use this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20968170/how-to-check-if-any-checkbox-is-checked-in-angular/20968682#20968682

Answer (score 0):

I think most people would have used `c` as their model and then tied `ng-model` to some property on `c`.  Then your list is really just `item.ColorList`

```
$scope.ColorList = [ { ID: 1,Name:"Red" },{ ID: 2,Name:"Green" },{ ID: 3,Name:"Blue" }];

<label data-ng-repeat="c in item.ColorList">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="c.Active" value="{{c.ID}}" /><span>{{c.Name}}</span> 
 </label>
```

---

```
$scope.getSelected = function(item){
     var results = [];
     angular.forEach(item.ColorList, function(c){
          if(c.Active){
              results.push(c);
          }
     });
     return results;
}
```