# Ionic checkbox check whether the checkbox is checked or not

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, ionic-framework

I use a ionic checkbox below is the html

```
   <ion-checkbox ng-repeat="ao in q.AnswerOptions"
              name="cb" ng-click="setAnswerOptionSelected(q.Id,ao.Id)">
    {{ao.Text}}
</ion-checkbox>
```

in my controller i need to find out whether the select check box is checked or not . I cannot use the ng-model way to finding out that is add a property to my ao say

```
IsSelected
```

and use that in my check box.

```
ng-model="ao.IsSelected"
```

Can i find out the state of the ionic checkbox that is whether it is checked or not in the controller method as in the above code.

Basically on call to setAnswerOptionSelected method i should be either be able to pass the current ionic checkbox and then check whether its checked or not. ?

> setAnswerOptionSelected

Answer (score 8):

I was able to find a solution by declaring a dummy model on ng-init and passing the value of the variable as a parameter to the ng-click method.

```
<ion-checkbox ng-repeat="ao in q.AnswerOptions"
              name="cb" ng-change="setAnswerOptionSelected(qg.Id,q.Id,ao.Id,checkStatus)"
              ng-init='checkStatus=false'
              ng-model="checkStatus">
    {{ao.Text}}
</ion-checkbox>
```

found the solution from the post

> [How to check if any Checkbox is checked in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23818360/581157)

Answer (score 2):

I have list of checkbox and i am able to get selected checkbox list from that list using below code which is mix of 2 answers of Stack overflow :

**HTML :**

```
<ion-checkbox ng-model="isChecked" ng-repeat="asset in assets" ng-change="checkedOrNot(asset, isChecked, $index)" ng-init='isChecked=false'>
</ion-checkbox>
```

**JS :**

```
$scope.isChecked = false;
    $scope.selected = [];
    $scope.checkedOrNot = function (asset, isChecked, index) {
        if (isChecked) {
            $scope.selected.push(asset);
        } else {
            var _index = $scope.selected.indexOf(asset);
            $scope.selected.splice(_index, 1);
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something as simple as this ?

```
<ion-checkbox class="item-checkbox-right checkbox-energized item" 
    style="border:0;" 
    ng-model="check"
    ng-change="printCheck(check)">
    Check me out yo!
</ion-checkbox>
```

and in js

```
 $scope.printCheck = function(check) {
        console.log(check);
 }
```