# AngularJS - Submit items selected from list

Tags: angularjs, submit

I want if checkbox selected and click submit button insert data to database.

```
<tbody>
  <tr ng-repeat="item in rows | filter:search">
    <td>{{ite m.isbn}}</td>
    <td>{{item.kitap_ismi}}</td>
    <td>{{item.sayfa_sayisi}}</td>
    <td>{{item.baski_yili}}</td>
    <td>{{item.isim}}</td>
    <td>{{item.kategori_isim}}</td>
    <td>{{item.yayinevi_isim}}</td>                     
    <td><center><input type="checkbox"></center></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>                        

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-success">
```

Comment: Please check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20968170/how-to-check-if-any-checkbox-is-checked-in-angular

Comment: its not help. click button selectedrow insert database or json

Answer (score 0):

**Here you have working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/an22bv63/1/)**

I'm adding '_metaSelected' property to every row on selection:

```
<input type="checkbox", ng-model="item._metaSelected">
```

And on submit:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" ng-click="submit()">
```

Sending only items with '_metaSelected' property:

```
$scope.submit = function(){
  //- Clear
  $scope.submitedRows = [];

  //- Choose selected rows
  angular.forEach($scope.rows, function(row){
    if(row._metaSelected){
      //- Remove _metaSelected property before submition
      delete row['_metaSelected'];

      $scope.submitedRows.push(row);    
    }
  });
  //- POST with submitedRows as payload
  //- yourService.save($scope.submitedRows)
}
```

Comment: Thank you. i need to give the date when the user presses the button

Comment: Date? You mean 'data'. And in attached fiddle I'm handling click action. You have to place there your own service with POST method to your server.

Comment: Thank you man. so sorry but i dont understand how insert submitedRows data to db

Comment: I what programming language is your backend?

Comment: my database postgresql language php

Comment: http://code.runnable.com/UoNmllRhIpEiAABb/how-to-insert-rows-into-postgresql-table-for-php-and-pgsql

Comment: ok. but  i need to insert checkbox selectedrow to db e.g. item.isbn, item.kitap_ismi

Comment: its not work why $http.post("http://localhost:8080/insert.php",{'isbn': $scope.submitedRows[0].isbn},{headers:{
   
   'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
  }
   
   
  }).success(function(data, status, headers, config){
            console.log("inserted Successfully");
        });

Comment: Past console output.