# Sending pristine inputs to angular controller

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, forms

I am using some checkboxes in my angular app which are checked by default.These are in ng-pristine state.How can I receive these inputs in my controller when the form is posted without making them dirty.
`<input type="checkbox" name="c1" name="favoriteColors" ng-model="data.checkboxtest[1]" ng-checked="true">
<input type="checkbox" name="c2" name="favoriteColors" ng-model="data.checkboxtest[2]">`

Controller:

`$scope.submitNewTemplate = function(){
    console.log($scope.data.checkboxtest)
}`

returns "undefined"

Answer (score 0):

see i have added demo code for check box here

please have a look on it.
May be this will help you

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.testModel = {
    item1: true,
    item2: false,
    item3: false
  };
  $scope.submit = function() {
    console.log($scope.testModel);
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.6/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">

  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="test1" ng-model="testModel.item1" />Testing</label>
  <br />
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="test2" ng-model="testModel.item2" />Testing 2</label>
  <br />
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="test3" ng-model="testModel.item3" />Testing 3</label>
  <br />
  <input type="button" ng-click="submit()" value="Submit" />
  <pre>{{testModel|json}}</pre>
</body>

</html>
```

Hope this will help you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Good question, I have never taken the time to look into this.
Here is a bit of a workaround to what you want,
 but it does the job.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="c1" name="favoriteColors" ng-model="data.checkboxtest[1]" ng-init='data.checkboxtest[1] = true'>
<input type="checkbox" name="c2" name="favoriteColors" ng-model="data.checkboxtest[2]" ng-init='data.checkboxtest[2] = false'>
```

Here is where I found the answer [How to check if any Checkbox is checked in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20968170/how-to-check-if-any-checkbox-is-checked-in-angular)

Comment: thanks for the answer.but that doesn't solve my problem. actually my checkbox inputs will change dynamically through a dropdown without touching the checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly checked for  `true` or `false`

```
if($scope.data.checkboxtest[1]){
  //checked
}else{
   //unchecked
}
```