# AngularJS: generate checkboxes with ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

i got a code which i understand but a small area is not clear. so help me to understand please.

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <label ng-repeat="(color,enabled) in colors">
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="colors[color]" /> {{color}} 
  </label>
  <p>colors: {{colors}}</p>

<script>
  var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

  app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope){
      $scope.colors = {Blue: true, Orange: true};
  });
</script>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/U4VD61?p=preview

see this line `ng-model="colors[color]"` how this line automatically set checkbox checked or unchecked state because in code we do not mention `checked = true or false` then how angular automatically extract true or false from model and set it in checkbox.......this is not clear. please guide me.

Comment: http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/AngularJS-Check-whether-CheckBox-is-checked-or-unchecked.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

angular `ng-model` checks checkbox if `ng-model` value is `true`. You have given `Blue` as `true`. So `ng-model` checks the checkbox.

If you using angular `ng-model` it will automaticaly fills value of any form field. You don't need to put `ng-checked = true` or something

[How to check if any Checkbox is checked in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20968170/how-to-check-if-any-checkbox-is-checked-in-angular)

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bcheckbox%5D

Comment: Do you have a link that explains this ? Not that I don't believe you but I'd like to read up on that.

Comment: You could check with angularjs input checkbox page

Comment: yes i understand thanks a lot. i would mark it as answer :)